# Crash in Coredata on system restart after improper shutdown of system

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I faced a issue that I never thought of. Please let me understand what could be the case and how to resolve it? What I am feeling the coredata readwrite process could not complete properly hence it got corrupted.

In my application I am using coredata. I was doing some task downloading some files from web and saving thier entried in coreata that involves reading-writing from coredata. And suddenly the battery went (100% discharged, and system shutdown).

Then I charge the system and start the app, I could see a crash happened in  `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

The crash logs(few parts) are here:

```
Thread 2 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 0x60800027dbc0
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8ea2b0dd objc_msgSend + 29
1   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff93e1aa4a _PFRetainedObjectIDCore + 330
2   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff93e01b6e -[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:] + 686
3   via.intralinks.com              0x000000010442caf0 -[EncryptedStore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1897
4   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff93e7b389 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3945
5   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff93e855ab gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 171
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8a380c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8a381e5e _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 57
8   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff93e745a2 _perform + 194
9   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff93dc65a5 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 533
10  com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff93dc4dfb -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 587
11  via.intralinks.com              0x0000000104384432 -[AKVCoreDataManager objectWithEntityName:withAttributeKey:andValue:sortDescriptorKey:] + 270
```

Comment: Hi Anoop,
Could you pleas let us know whether you using multiple Context or single context for operation(Downloading, Reading & writing)?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS: Single context

Comment: Sorry, but that's no where near enough information to go on.

Comment: I would like to ask to you please use multiple context. One context for downloading & other for updating UI on main context.

 One option is that create an private queue context on independent persistent stack & second option is that create private queue on same persistent stack.

let me know if you want more information on the same.

Comment: What error message(s) show up in Xcode's console? The stack trace only shows that you're crashing during a fetch request, but it's impossible to say what caused that without more information.